# Using javascript to check if user has entered a correct value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a number guessing game where a random number between 1-50 is selected, and the user has to guess it. I am currently stuck where regardless if the user enters a right or wrong answer, my WRONG alert pops up. I am wondering where I went wrong, any help is appreciated.

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
console.log(randomNumber);
var userGuess = document.querySelector("#guess");
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", submit, false);

function submit() {

  if (parseInt(userGuess) === randomNumber) {
    alert("You Win");
  } else {
    alert("You Lose");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="guess" type="text">
<br />
<button id="submit" type="submit">Guess 1</button>
<button id="submit2" type="submit">Guess 2</button>
<button id="submit3" type="submit">Guess 3</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="hotCold"></p>
<h2>Your guesses</h2>
<p id="prevGuesses"></p>
```

Comment: `userGuess` is an element, parsing an element to number returns `NaN`, which is not equal even with itself.

Comment: note: when you submit a form, a new page is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `parseInt` on the actual `<input>` element, not the inputted value (which will return `NaN`). The actual inputted string is in the `value` property of the element, so replace this:

```
if (parseInt(userGuess) === randomNumber)
```

with this:

```
if (parseInt(userGuess.value) === randomNumber)
```

and it should work.

Note that making the `userGuess` variable be initialized with the value (i.e. `var userGuess = document.querySelector("#guess").value` instead of `var userGuess = document.querySelector("#guess")`) will not work, as while DOM elements are dynamically updated, the `value` property is a simple string, and so `userGuess` will be set to an empty string (the starting value of the `<input>`) and will not be updated when the user inputs a number.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! I knew I was missing something simple. Appreciate the note as well, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `value of input`, so replace

```
if (parseInt(userGuess) === randomNumber) {
```

with

```
if (parseInt(userGuess.value) === randomNumber) {
```

And you good to go.